# Why is new sub-site appearing in wrong place on Quick Launch (SharePoint 2007)?

Tags: quick-launch, sub-site

[image]

Several months ago I added two sub-sites to the SharePoint 2007 site I manage, and they correctly show in the Sites area of the Quick Launch. Today I added a third sub-site. I thought I did it the exact same way, but it ended up as a whole separate category on the QL (at the same level as Documents, Lists, Discussions, Sites, and People and Groups).

Can you help me get the Trainers Team sub-site where it belongs? (By the way, I do NOT have the Quick Launch option under Site Settings > Look and Feel. My option says Navigation.)

Thank you!

Comment: What all options you can see when you click the Navigation link?

Answer (score 0):

You can see only Navigation because `Publishing` feature is enabled. To edit, move or delete a Quick Launch link do as follow

1. Site Actions -> Site Settings
2. Look and Feel -> Navigation
3. Navigation Editing and Sorting

   - To Edit the link - Click on Edit
   - To move a link - You can use the "Move Up" or "Move Down" button
   - To delete a link - You can click on Delete
4. Click OK.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, I could not see the list you pictured, and it turns out that was the fault of IE9. I switched to Firefox and was able to see the list and move things to where I need them. :-)